# On dragging mat-expansion-panel, tinymce editor value inside expansion panel body is getting cleared

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, tinymce, angular-cdk

I have kept tinymce editor inside mat-expansion-panel body and that mat-accordion is cdkDropList, whereas mat-expansion-panel is cdkDrag. When I tried to drag a mat-expansion-panel value inside tinymce editor is not displaying and it becomes readonly. But I checked value is not deleted, it is present inside formControl and also in textarea of tinymce. Only Iframe of tinymce is getting cleared and readonly.

I have searched but couldn't find or get any clue for it.

One person posted the question with https://stackblitz.com/edit/tinymce-drag-drop-problem link. Then after that he only posted it's answer here https://stackblitz.com/edit/tinymce-drag-drop-problem-kmgwuz, but it is with some bugs. Data coming after drag is different.

Even On Drag and drop of mat-expansion-panel, tinymce value should be visible with readwrite permission.

Comment: Anybody who knows the answer please help on this